# How to hide the Share and Copy link options in a PDF for Visitors - 365 Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, pdf, share, copylink

I am having a problem with the way PDFs display.  When a person with **Visitor/Read** privileges opens a PDF in the Modern experience **Share**, **Copy link** and **Download** display in the toolbar of the PDF.

Even worse, when they click on Share or Copy the *browser locks up*!  As an owner I don't have any issues since owners are the only permission level that can share. Is there a fix? If there isn't a fix for the Modern experience is there a way to launch PDFs to the Classic view?

[image]

Comment: Are you showing the pdf in the browser by clicking on the file in SharePoint? If so, check to see if it is locked by a browser plugin. Please check user permissions, try removing them and adding them again. Also, switch browsers to see if the same thing happens. If it's open in the app, it's not a good idea to go back to the classic view unless you roll back the version.

Comment: Are you showing the pdf in the browser by clicking on the file in SharePoint? If so, check to see if it is locked by a browser plugin. Please check user permissions, try removing them and adding them again. Answer: This is the way it works for everyone.  Also tried another permission and works the same way. Also, switch browsers to see if the same thing happens. Answer: Can't use other browsers. If it's open in the app, it's not a good idea to go back to the classic view unless you roll back the version.                                  Also, I need the PDF to open in a new tab.